# Customize Google Assistant in Android Auto app

Tags: android, android-auto

Is it possible to customize Google Assistant experience in Android Auto media app? I'm building an app that is playing news (radio auditions, podcasts etc.) and Google Assistant is optimized to provide responses that are focused on "Music". For example when I'm asking for "Guns and Roses" then this search query is forwarded to my app and I can provide a search results to the user. But my app is more "news" oriented and when I'm for example asking to search for "sports news" then Google Assistant is not letting me to respond to this request.

My question is: is it possible to customize Google Assistant behaviour here? Or, even better it would be to force it to forward all of the "not recognized" queries to the app.

Comment: I'm thinking this is the wrong place to ask how to customize google assistant.

Comment: @danny117 what do you think would be better place to ask about it? Google Issue Tracker is for sure not the best place also.

Comment: IDK also seems mildly that program would be making changes on behalf of user.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot customize Google Assistant but I don't think that is the question you want to be asking here.

I propose an alternative solution that Google already provides.
This is not exactly as you ask but you may be able to to say "Play Sports News on {your app name}".
If you register `ACTION_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH` and implement the `onPlayFromSearch()` callback, you may get the play command string routed to your app.
Please refer to the following Google document: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/interacting-with-assistant#playback_actions

Comment: i'm trying to make this exacte thing but google assistant not recognising my app, i did register ACTION_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH and implemented the onPlayFromSearch() but no luck. my app had been in the store for 3days.  So you have any idea what the problem could be? plz share 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771616/android-assistant-mediabrowserservice-voice-command-play-x-on-appname